# c# - underscore in fields name

Tags: c#, ssis, propertyinfo

I have a script task with some input fields, like 'field_of_example'. The script is like this:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{ 
Dictionary<string, string> body = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (PropertyInfo inputColumn in Row.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (!inputColumn.Name.EndsWith("IsNull") 
                {

                        body.Add(inputColumn.Name, inputColumn.GetValue(Row).ToString());

                }
```

the problem is that in inputColumn.Name I have 'fieldofexample' instead of 'field_of_example', is there any way to take the input name with underscores?

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the properties of class Input0Buffer. Try to use the `GetFields()` method instead.

Comment: do you have any suggestions about that? I've tried with: var temp= Row.GetType().GetFields(); but it is empty